# Mule Anypoint studio does not start

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio

I am pretty new to Mulesoft. Just installed Anypoint 4 and Java.
The Studio app crashes with the following error in its first step. I have IBM Integration bus toolkit which uses Java and Eclipse but does not have any issue.

I'm getting the following `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception:

```
!SESSION 2019-12-16 19:20:11.810 ----------------------------------------------- 
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=13.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-12-16 19:21:13.756
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
```

Comment: Hi, which class exactly is not found? You should paste the complete error message.

Comment: It would help if you posted the whole log. It is found here:

{your workspace}/.metadata/.log

Comment: Pleases find the  error log `code` !SESSION 2019-12-16 19:20:11.810 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=13.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-12-16 19:21:13.756
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

Answer (score 1):

unknown java.version=13.0.1

Anypoint studio needs AdoptJDK 8, although mule 4.2.0 plus runtime currently supports JDK 11.

please find the workaround below to make your studio work and co-exist with your 13.0 JDK.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.2/studio-configure-vm-task-wx